# Restoring dump file after MySQL server migration from 5.1.51 to 5.5.10 throws error 1064

Tags: mysql, migration, upgrade

On a Windows 7 machine running MySQL server 5.1.51 (both 64bit), before migrating to 5.5.10, I made a backup of my entire database using MySQL Administrator. After installing 5.5.10, I tried to restore the dump file but it throws one error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci  ; SELECT co_n' at line 9"
```

I tried restore through several MySQL applications (Workbench, SQLYog) and the command line, but all throw the same error. It also throws several warnings that are however not displayed.

Two questions:

1. Of course, can you help me resolve this issue? Do I have to edit the sql dump file in some way? That's cumbersome though, since it's over 3GB. I thought I had followed all the steps with respect to upgrading mentioned in the MySQL documentation, so now I am a bit frustrated and scared of data loss.
2. When restoring from the command line, how can I make `mysql.exe` log all warnings and errors to a text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OBSERVATION #1

MySQL provides upgrade scripts when migrating data from a previous major release. I usually do not use them. Here is what I do whenever I migrate from one major release to another:

mysqldump all databases except the mysql schema. The mysql schema from major release to major release is different.

Start with a fresh install of MySQL 5.5.10

Load all databases from the mysqldumps (except mysql) in MySQL 5.5.10

Now what about the mysql schema? You can dump it in a very special way.

This is what I do for Linux to dump the mysql schema from MySQL 5.1.51:

```
mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLGrants51.sql
```

This will produce all the SQL GRANT commands to recreate the users and permissions.

Since you are using Windows, you can do this:

```
mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A > C:\MySQLGrants51.sql
```

You would have to edit C:\MySQLGrants51.sql in notepad so that every line the file ends with a semicolon(;)

Now go into MySQL 5.5.10's client and run

source C:\MySQLGrants51.sql

OBSERVATION #2

"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_german1_ci ;

This error message has 'TYPE = MyISAM'. Shouldn't that read 'ENGINE = MyISAM' ?

Comment: hi rolando, #1: in fact i dumped ONLY my database, i think that should be ok since thus I'm not overwriting the mysql and other schemas? #2: maybe you are right, but i didn't write the dump file myself, so why would mysql dump create an error?

Comment: TYPE=MyISAM is backward compatible for MySQL 4.x. Try editing all TYPE= at the end of every CREATE TABLE statement to say ENGINE= instead

Comment: ok, i'll try to replace these but doubt whether this is the cause of the error since i would expect 5.5 to be compatible to backward syntax. another question: would it also work to overwrite the data folder of the new server with the one of the old (5.1.51) and then run mysql_upgrade?

Comment: I usually do not use them. It should work but I have heard many complaints. Give it a try anyway.

Comment: BTW I have clients with MySQL 5.1 and MySQL 5.5. I just ran "show variables like 'table_type';". That variable does not exist in MySQL 5.5

Comment: Issue resolved: You were right in that "TYPE = MyISAM" was wrong. It wasn't generated by mysqldump but was part of a stored procedure. I corrected it with a text editor for huge files and then it run smoothly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is repeat the dump, using the "mysqldump" tool. This is the only tool which is capable of making non-useless dumps. Other (particularly GUI) tools TRY, but they fail, because they aren't sufficiently well-tested, particularly in this kind of scenario.

Bin your dump, and make a new one using mysqldump. Use the version of mysqldump from 5.5, for preference.

Comment: while i already fixed the problem, i find your suggestions very helpful for the next time. thanks.